# Dataprep flow limited to ~15 imported datasets

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I would like to share one of my findings regarding dataprep product limitations.

I was construction flows in which I needed the combine a number of json files before further processing. The flows are then combined through references datasets at the end.

After a significant struggle I noticed that when the total number of json files used as input is lower than around 15, a dataflow job could be started.

However, going above this limit would cause a failure withouth any explanation.

It would be great if there is somebody who can give more insight into this issue:
* Why is there such a limitation?
* Is it another problem that could cause me to think there is a limitation?
* Is there a quick way to identify the sources of these types of issues/bugs in dataprep?
* Is there a workaround to increase the number of input files?

Cheers,
Bram

Comment: How do you import your json files? Personally, I had no problem for example using as an input dataset a storage directory including 20 json files. The resulting dataset consisted of all files concatenated, each row corresponding to a valid json object. Is that what you are looking to do? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Initial-Parsing-Steps_57344625#json) you can see conditions for your files to be successfully imported. Also, do you get an error message you could share?

Comment: Regarding your other questions: normally all product limitations should be tracked [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Product-Limitations_60720399). However this page already mentions that the provided list is not complete which most probably relates to the fact that dataprep is still in beta. Other than that, since all dataprep jobs are eventually ran in dataflow, all dataflow [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) should also apply.

Comment: The json files are transformed and  added togther  correctly when using a union. However, when the total number of imported datasets is higher than around 15 the dataflow job is not able to start. I think it has nothing to do with the fact that it are json files. But you say you where able to run a dataflow job through dataprep with 20 files? What if you do 30? And what do you mean with storage directory? Thanks!

Comment: By Storage directory I refer to a folder in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I still cannot reproduce your issue. Here's what I did: I created a new flow, imported one json and added a recipe. For the recipe's first step I used a UNION transformation, giving it 36 additional json files. I then also added two random transformations and ran the job which completed successfully after about 5 minutes. Is that similar to your scenario? Can you share any more details?

Comment: It is similar to my scenario but I'm still not able to start a dataflow job with that amount of imported datasets connected to a flow. I'm now checking if it might be due to the fact that I'm accidentally using an older version of the dataflow SDK... Any tips on this?

Comment: I would be surprised if this related to the SDK version. In any case, did you check it? Anything new that you can add here? If your problem insists, I would suggest that you update your original question with any significant info you can see in the dataflow side (e.g. error messages).

Answer (score 0):

I did have an issue with starting jobs in dataprep and it was solved by

- disabling the "profile results" option in the run page.